# error C2760: синтаксическая ошибка: непредвиденный токен ")"; требуется "выражение"

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет. Взял шаблонный пример паттерна стратегия с википедии
[Пример реализации (шаблонный параметр) С++](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Делаю под свою задачу. Необходимо передавать массив char в стратегии.

```
struct Strategy_1 {
void use(char* b1) 
{ 
    char* str = b1;
дальше идет алгоритм

struct Strategy_2 {
void use(char* b2) 
{ 
    char* strr = b2;
дальше второй алгоритм
```

Затем место, в котором сама ошибка (строчка с this)

```
template <class Operation>
struct Client : public Operation
{
void useStrategy(char*)
{
    this->use(char*);
}
};
```

ну и часть того, что в main

```
char* b1 = new char[t];
char* b2 = new char[t];

Client<Strategy_1> customClient1;
customClient1.useStrategy(b1);

Client<Strategy_2> customClient2;
customClient2.useStrategy(b2);
```

Если запустить просто пример из википедии, то все работает. Ошибка возникает при передаче char в качестве аргумента. Подскажите, пожалуйста, Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так а что это за белиберда: `this->use(char*)`? Это выглядит как вызов функции. Но что делает  этот `char*` внутри скобок? Что вы хотели сказать этим `char*`?

Comment: Ничего) но без него сама студия начинает много что подсвечивать красным. А с charом внутри ничего не подсвечивает, но не запускается

Comment: Она перестала подсвечивать, так как слишком сильно афигела от таких строк. Вы видимо хотели написать `void useStrategy(char* parameter) {this->use(parameter);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное вы уже понели, что роли выполняют обьекты, а не типы, и поэтому нужно исправить :

```
void useStrategy(char* p)
{
    this->use(p);
}
```

Но это не избавит вас от логических ошибок. Вы выделяете память под массив символов: 
char* b1 = new char[t];
char* b2 = new char[t];
но  без инициализации приступаете к использованию этих массивов, передавая их в аргумент функций. В итоге вы работаете  с мусором.

Можно еще обратить внимание на то, что вы определяете шаблон класса,  из чего вы в дальнейщем имеете возможность инcтанцировать всего два типа, поскольку другие не будут иметь соответствующую функцию.  Таким образом можно легко запутать себя и других.  И второе, вы не имеете возможность передать в функцию константную строку, хотя функция не модефицирует исходную строку... Из многих вариантов решений вы  выбрали худший. А могли бы сделать, например, так:

```
struct Strategy {
    virtual void use(const char*) = 0;
    //...
};

struct Strategy_1 : public Strategy {
    void use(const char* b1) override
    {
        //std::cout << b1 << std::endl;
        //...
    }
    //...
};

struct Strategy_2 : public Strategy {
    void use(const char* b2)  override
    {
        //std::cout << b2 << std::endl;
        //...
    }
    //...
};

void useStrategy(Strategy& s, const char* p)  { s.use(p); }

int main()
{   
    //const char* b1 = "Strategy_1", * b2 = "Strategy_2";
    Strategy_1 s1;
    useStrategy(s1, b1);
    Strategy_2 s2;
    useStrategy(s2, b2);
    //...   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, постараюсь переделать, пока не поздно) best practise от опытных коллег всегда важно!)